# Monorepo referring to NextJs module

Tags: next.js, monorepo

Packages in a TypeScript monorepo...

- `web` (NextJs)
- `server` (Node)
- `lib` (plain library)

From `server` I can refer to `lib` with...

```
import { something } from "@acme/lib/dist/somemodule"
```

That works.

From `server` I want to refer to `web`.  However

```
import { somethingelse } from "@acme/web/src/someothermodule"
```

passes linting, but when running gives `Error: Cannot find module '@acme/web/src/someothermodule'`.  I'm sure that is because the compiled js does not reside in `src`, but in `.next`.  But in `.next` it is bundled.  So how can I refer to `web` from `server`?